# Cocos2d-x 3.0 Schedule Error2276

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I get this error:

> '&': illegal operation on bound member function expression

in this line:

```
this->schedule(schedule_selector(TimerMethod), 0.01);
```

and i dont know why because there is no "&" character in the code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 0):

Pass method name with class name `ClassName::methodName` in `schedule_selector` micro.

Let's suppose Xyz is name of any class that is child of `Layer`.

```
class Xyz : public Layer {

   public:

   virtual bool init();
   void TimerMethod(float dt) {

   }
}
```

scheduling in Layer's `init()` method in this way :

```
bool Xyz::init(){

     if(!Layer::init())
          return false;

    this->schedule(schedule_selector(Xyz::TimerMethod), 0.01);
    return true;
}
```